# Magento: confirm, before entering a category

Tags: php, html, css, categories, magento-1.8

i am new in magento. i want customers to answer a question before entering to a category in Magento 1.8.1.
for example i wanna ask a question like this: are you 18 or more? if a customers clicked on a adult stuff category and he/she would allowed in if answer is yes.
how can i do that?
pleas explain by details. thanx

Comment: On category view page, you should open confirm box using jquery for confirmation of your question. If user press OK then return true else redirect to home page.

Comment: can you explain more? i mean by details. cause i'm new in Magento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could done it using jquery. Here is sample code -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
               var conf = confirm('are you 18 or more ?');
               if(conf == true) {
                   return true;
               } else {
                   document.location.href = 'http://google.com';
               }
            });
</script>
```

Whenever you enter category page. This confirmation box will appear.

Comment: which files should i create and which file should i copy this code to. can you explain by details.

Comment: As you are saying for category page, then you should write the code in "\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\category\view.phtml" file.

Comment: i added this code to view.phtml but i get this error:
`
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '$' in/home/dokanche/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml on line43`
.in which line should i add this code?
@TBI

Comment: You have to add this on top of file, use <script> tag along with this.
Code is updated

Comment: i added this code and i tried several times but it doesn't work. this is my view.phtml. would you mind show me the exact place to add the code?
http://www.4shared.com/file/M9p259fvba/view.html
@TBI